# Vscode mysql issue

Tags: mysql, visual-studio-code

Has anyone run into this issue on vscode mysql?

I've searched everywhere and cannot find a solution. If anyone has any idea or has come across this, the help would be greatly appreciated.

**client option 'pooling.maxidletime' does not support value 'nan'**

The issue is coming from the sqltools extension connection on vscode.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the `connectionTimeout` parameter in your connection settings, like so:

```
{
  "mysqlOptions": {
    "authProtocol": "xprotocol"
  },
  "previewLimit": 50,
  "server": "localhost",
  "port": 33060,
  "driver": "MySQL",
  "name": "MySQL_v8",
  "database": "some-db",
  "username": "root",
  "password": "123456789",
  "connectionTimeout": 15
}
```

More on this in [here](https://github.com/mtxr/vscode-sqltools/issues/402).

Answer (score 0):

in this answer im assuming that you're using vscode and your're programming in mysql.
go to the client command line, type your password.
type "create database database_name" and press enter.
now go to vscode and tap in the sql icon at your left or rigth.
create new connection.
select mysql.
provide the details, make sure that your database name is, as mentoned above "database_name", and make sure that user is the same as when you're installing mysql, the same goes to the password.
select connect now.
type your sql code.
save it.
2 file will pop up, and that's completly normal.
click run on active connection.